# Stretching DIV to 100% height and width of window but not less than 800x600px

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a page that needs to stretch and resize with with window and I've managed to do that but I need that the "inner div" (`#pgContent`) stretch if the window is resized to higher dimensions but that it doesn't shrink more than, let's say for example 800 x 600 px. 
As I have it now it stretches well but it also shrinks more than I want!

It's working as I want in width but not in height!?

Here's a visual example:

[image: example]

My CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

/*| PAGE LAYOUT |*/

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*text-align: center;*/ /*IE doesn't ~like this*/
  cursor: default;
}

#pgWrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  /*min-height: 600px;*/ /* THIS SHOULD WORK BUT IT DOESN'T */
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}

#pgContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #CCC;
}

#footWrapper {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 940px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #C00;
}

/*| END PAGE LAYOUT |*/
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="pgWrapper">
  <div id="pgContent">
    This DIV should stretch with window but never lower than for example 800px x 600px!<br />
    If window size is lower then scrollbars should appear.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footWrapper">
  <div id="footLft"></div>
  <div id="footRgt"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

If someone could give me a help on this I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second min-height will overwrite the first one.

Use a height of 100% and min-height of 680px;

```
#pgWrapper {
z-index: 1;
min-height: 600px;
height: 680px;
min-width: 800px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot... I keep forgetting that CCS follows the order of commands and overwrites previous.

Answer (score 0):

I belive height auto is messing with your stretching, commenting it out made your styles behave much better. Of course it might be down to different browsers

```
#pgWrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    min-height: 100%;
    /*height: auto !important;*/
    min-height: 680px;
    /* THIS SHOULD WORK BUT IT DOESN'T */
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
}
```

Working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/QqMeC/4/

Comment: That is probably not helping neither doing anything so I removed it. The problem was solved thanks to the answer of Michael Terry. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following in #pgWrapper

```
  overflow: auto;
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jonocairns/LA8hg/

Comment: No, but thanks anyway! Its just the order of the CSS properties like Michael Terry pointed.